# How to package python into virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

How to package Python itself into `virtualenv`? Is this even possible?

I'm trying to run python on a machine which it is not installed on, and I thought `virtualenv` made this possible. It activates, but can't run any Python.

Answer (score 1):

When setting up the `virtualenv` (this can also be done if it already set up) simply do:

```
python -m virtualenv -p python env
```

And Python will be added to the `virtualenv`, and will become the default python of it.

The version of Python can also be passed, as `python` uses the first version found in the PATH.

Answer (score 1):

`virtualenv` makes it convenient to use multiple python versions in different projects on the same machine, and isolate the `pip install` libraries installed by each project. It doesn’t install or manage the overall python environment. Python must be installed on the machine before you can install or configure the `virtualenv` tool itself or switch into a virtual environment.

Side note, consider using `virtualenvwrapper` — great helper for `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the Operating System you are using.

In case you're using Windows, you don't use virtualenv for this. Instead you:

1. Download the [Python embeddable package](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/python-3.7.3-embed-amd64.zip)
2. Unpack it
3. Uncomment `import site` in the `python37._pth` file (only if you want to add additional packages)
4. Manually copy your additional packages (the ones you usually install with pip) to `Lib\site-packages` (you need to create that directory first, of course)

Such a python installation is configured in such a way that it can be moved and run from any location.

You only have to ensure the Microsoft C Runtime is installed on the system (but it almost always already is). See the [documentation note](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/windows.html#the-embeddable-package):

> Note The embedded distribution does not include the Microsoft C Runtime and it is the responsibility of the application installer to provide this. The runtime may have already been installed on a user’s system previously or automatically via Windows Update, and can be detected by finding ucrtbase.dll in the system directory.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to install python in some location you have the permissions to do so.